# conformal map between unit disk and G

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question which I don't know how to approach. Let $G$ be the region between the two circles $C_1=${$z:|z-1|=1$}and $C_2=${$z:|z-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$}. Find $f$ that maps $G$ conformally onto the open unit disk.

At first I thought maybe the conformal map will be realized by a mobius transform but then I thought the boundary of $G$ is wedge of circles while the boundary of disk is just a cirlce hence there cannot exist a map that is biholomorphic from the closure of $G$ to the closed disk so the map $f$ cannot be a mobius transformation.

Then I thought that I will be able to come up with a map if I manage to find a map to convert $G$ to an annulus and then apply log to convert it into a strip and then move the strip around and extend it and apply exponential to map it to the unit disk.

Is this the right approach also I don't know how to map $G$ to an annulus.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285450/find-a-conformal-map-from-two-circle-tangent-to-each-other-from-inside-to-the-up for a very similar problem.

Comment: Thanks thats indeed very useful